# Content width 100% showing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

I've had a look for problems similar to this, but none of the fixes prescribed in the other questions have worked in my case. Basically, my body width is set to 100%, and I have no padding or margins in any other divs, and yet I still have a strange horizontal scrollbar at the bottom and about 50px of blank space to the right of the layout. It should stop where the red line is here:

[image]

Have racked my brain and racked the questions here, but have no clue what's going on. Would be extremely grateful for advice. Relevant CSS:

```
body, html {
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:12pt;
background:#f2f2f2;
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
border:0;
/* overflow:hidden; */
}

#menubar {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
background:#FDBB30;
height:80px;
width:100%;
font-weight:bold;
}

#content {
position:absolute;
top:80px;
width:92%;
left:50px;
background:#ffffff;
height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

EDIT: HTML in the test page:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="menubar"><?php require 'menubar.php'; ?></div>
<div id="content">
<h1>Avis libertatis volebit semper</h1>
<h2>avis libertatis volebit semper</h2>
<p>avis libertatis volebit semper</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could the blank space of about 50px be caused by `left: 50px` ?

Comment: This is what I thought but I have no idea how I would then remedy that, nor why the scrollbar would appear.

Comment: add your code to some fiddle

Comment: Please include the HTML part in your question. Also, what is this "magic number" width:92%; ? Best regards,

Comment: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfLob5x3/ - not sure why it's working there, but not in actuality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `width: 92%` and `left: 50px`.

At about a window width of 600px, the content will be `600*0.92` = `552px` width. Add the left position of `50px` to it, and the total width is `602px`. Which is wider that you window width.

So instead of using `left: 50px`, use `left: 4%`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfLob5x3/)

Comment: It may work in the demo, but it isn't working on the site itself: http://oulibdems.co.uk/test.php

Comment: The problem is `.menulogo`. Change the `left: 10%` to `padding-left: 10%` and it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/jfLob5x3/2/

Comment: Genius! All is dandy now - why did that cause such a problem?

Comment: Because you place that div relative. It takes 100% of it's parent width, and then is placed 10% from the left, total 110%. You could also change the position from relative to absolute. It will then be only as width as its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be your browser allowing space for a scroll bar?

Comment: No: problem persists on both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS as shown below:

```
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:50px;
    width:calc (100%-50px);
    background:#ffffff;
    height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Notice that line: `width:calc (100%-50px);`. Alternatively, you can use left:4%; and width:92% (as pointed out by @LinkinTED): both solutions should work. I would also recommend to clean up your actual page HTML: it seems inconsistent with your description.

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: And what is that div id="container"? You did not include it in CSS. Just remove it from HTML and see if it's working. Best regards,

Comment: Don't forget to click; CTRL+F5 to clear the cache. It may help.

Comment: Why didn't you show us the exact page before? It's very different from your description. There is whole bunch of other elements, which may have impact on the result. Plus, it seems that you have one extra </div></div>. Clean up your HTML and it will be working as shown in the DEMO. Best regards,